# Why do I get AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace' in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to standardize my data in my csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
my_city = pd.read_csv('sample4_addlink.csv')['City'].unique()

my_city
Out[70]: 
array(['Lancaster', 'Canton', 'Edison', ..., 'Upton', 'Irvington',
       'El Cerrito'], dtype=object)
```

Now as you see in my_city, there are some cities with space between names like El Cerrito. I want to replace the space with an underscore

```
my_cities =my_city.replace(" ", "_")
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-71-53c4a0662dd7>", line 1, in <module>
    my_cities =my_city.replace(" ", "_")

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I get this error when I use the .replace function. What is the best way to get around this?

Comment: this is because `unique()` returns an array, you can instead use `.drop_duplicates()` to return a series post which you should be able to access the methods for a series. May be something like `pd.read_csv('sample4_addlink.csv',usecols=['City']).drop_duplicates()`

Comment: i think its able to drop duplicates but it does not replace with underscore

Comment: use `my_city.replace(" ", "_",regex=True)` or `my_city.str.replace(" ", "_")`

Answer (score -1):

It's because [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) returns an `ndarray` or `ExtensionArray` object depending on the data type of the input series.

Use `drop_duplicates` and the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) accessor instead:

```
my_city = pd.read_csv('sample4_addlink.csv')['City'].drop_duplicates().str.replace(' ', '_')
```